# How to fix error while installing dotenv and uvloop

Tags: python, pip, python-dotenv

I am trying to install few modules specifically **dotenv** using pip in python But I got an error

I have tried updating pip version and updating setuptool but problem still exist.

I tried to install **dotenv** using pip it showed installing message for few minutes after that it showed error instead of installing it. here are the few lines of the error I got

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [67 lines of output]
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\users\rajj\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 82, in fetch_build_egg
          subprocess.check_call(cmd)
        File "C:\users\rajj\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\users\\rajj\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\tmpz17tfqwd', '--quiet', 'distribute']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
     
      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Comment: Please show all that 67 lines of output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have provided the code which contains direct cause, sir

Answer (score 20):

How are you installing dotenv? Usually people forget the correct package is [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) not [dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/dotenv/):

`pip install python-dotenv`

[Here](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/issues/53) are some other friends in the same boat :)

Comment: this was a lifesaver